# How to do my button div in the bottom always?

Tags: html, css

When I reduces the window, I saw the bottom in the "bottom" of the size that the window has, but I want that no matter what size the window is, the bottom div will be in the bottom of the page. What should I do to do it?

My bottom div:

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="#">
<img class="imgCenter" src="image.png" width="50" height="50">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

if its matter, my wrapper style is:

```
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Thanks!

Comment: why is your wrapper absolutely positioned?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use #bottom instead of .bottom since you are referencing your div with its id. Also, you can remove the margin: 0 auto or just change it to margin: 0 since your div has a width of 100% the auto won't do anything.

Comment: Yes im sorry, its a # and not . in the code, I copied it with mistake. And I changed to margin: 0 but it's still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full CSS solution that doesn't require a fixed position:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

You'll want to use the `wrapper` class around your content and `foooter/push` around the div you want at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute position definition:** The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

So maybe the problem is your wrapper ancestor position, make it `position:relative` and make us know about what happens!

anyway, it's an ID(#) not class(.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a mistake in css file. You use class element, but in html you have defined id element. That's mean you need #bottom instead of .bottom.
Second, my suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/p2xe6jhr/

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="#">
<img class="imgCenter" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/black_sedan_car_clip_art_20377.jpg" width="50" height="50">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the purpose of your wrapper div to be absolutely centered, but it is the root of your problem.

1. Assuming you want to keep your wrapper div and not touch it at all, change the `#bottom` CSS position to `position: relative` and you will achieve it being exactly where you want it to be, inside the wrapper div which is center positioned. *This is strange behavior but its your behavior*
2. **My Solution**: remove all the CSS style from your wrapper div, then watch how your `#bottom` div goes straight to the bottom of your page as you want it to.

Any other questions? Please comment below.

Comment: Thanks, I do it for do a equal space between the #header div and the #bottom div to the content space (in my case, #home). You have a new way to do it please?

Comment: @Roy add the relevant code for your home, header div to your question, I can work based off that

Comment: thanks for helping. Thats a long text code. I have main bar and logo in the #header div, in the #bottom you see... and in the #home just some content like text. All I want that the #home content will be in the middle and the center of the page (responsive of course) and as a result the space between the #header and the #home and between #home to #bottom will be equal. Again thanks for helping :)